# Is "even if..." followed by present or future tense?

Tags: tenses, conditionals, future

Is it correct to say:

> even if only James Bond will benefit from...

or

> even if only James Bond benefits from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Even if* is **never** followed by a future tense. The correct alternative is:

> Even if only James Bond benefits from...

Comment: I agree you can make a case for saying that 'even if' is never followed by 'will' if the main clause itself contains 'will'. Example: "She will not succeed, even if she works from now until Christmas." But using 'will' after 'even if' seems perfectly acceptable in other constructions: "I think you should ahead with your plan, even if it will only benefit James Bond."

Comment: I accept that *some* of [these 3,180,000 written instances](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22even+if+you+will%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books of *even if you will* may not exactly match our current context, but I think you're *way* out on a limb if you think none of them do. Or that any that do are just "bad grammar".

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the (currently) accepted answer. I see nothing wrong with...

> Even if only you will benefit, it's worth doing.

In defiance of pedants everywhere, I deny that there's any significant nuance differentiating...

> Even if only you benefit, it will be worth doing.
>
> Even if only you benefit, it would be worth doing.
>
> Even if only you will benefit, it's worth doing.
>
> Even if only you will benefit, it'll be worth doing.
>
> Even if only you would benefit, it's worth doing.
>
> Even if only you would benefit, it'll be worth doing.
>
> etc., etc.

...and I certainly see no point in debarring any combination on the grounds that it's somehow "not grammatical". The fact of the matter is all these variations occur, and it would be unlikely even for the speaker to choose one over another to convey some subtle shade of meaning. The possibility of his audience actually apprehending any such subtle distinction is effectively zero.

Comment: Speaking for pedants everywhere, I feel fully defied. But you mispronounced _pedant_.

Comment: Dang! I thought only my cat could hear me stomping around and ranting!

Comment: I agree with FF here. Why are people so determined to constrain expression with silly, arbitrary rules? Even if someone finds multiple citations to the contrary, I will continue to feel free to finish this type of sentence with a future tense. Keep on fighting the good fight, FumbleFingers!

Comment: @Robusto: And even if no-one else will, **I'll** upvote your comment! (plus I freely admit I upvoted *before* typing this comment! :)

Answer (score 2):

Hypothetical clauses that are headed by *if* (including *even if*) may only use the modal auxiliary verb *will* (or *won't*) in its [**Deontic**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) sense of 'intend, be willing', and not in its **Epistemic** sense of predicted necessity.

- *Frank won't hand in his homework.* (epistemic, a prediction)
- *If Frank won't hand in his homework, he'll tell you.* (deontic, *willing*)
- *If Frank doesn't hand in his homework, there'll be trouble.* (no modal, future)

Since there is [no future tense in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html), futurity is inferred rather than marked *per se*. Common constructions include  *be going to*, the present tense (as here), or some modal auxiliary (*will, may, can, should, must*, etc).

Comment: If there’s no future tense in English, then [what the devil do you call this?](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html) A future ***BLAHBLAH***?  I don’t think so. Calling it the future is perfectly fine. People are way too intense about ‘tense’ ≣ ‘one-word inflection’ around here. It smacks of Humpty-Dumptyism. What’s next? Pretending that present indicative and present subjunctive are the same tense, just different moods? That gets no one anywhere.

Comment: There are exceptions to this rule; when the *if*-clause is still in the future when viewed from the perspective of the main clause. From the internet: "If you will not be able to attend a class, let the instructor know as soon as possible."

Comment: @tchrist: I just like to use terminology correctly, just as many of us like to use English grammar correctly. There is a precise sense of _tense_, as you know, and then there is the use of _tense_ that means "some feature of a word" and leads to usages like _the passive tense, the subjunctive tense, the future perfect tense, the conditional tense,_ and even _the plural tense_. That's not helpful; you may not like the way I use the words, but I will continue to use them this way because it's the right professional way.

Comment: You may, just like me and everybody else, use grammatical terms any way you please. Feel free. I won't tell you how to say what you mean, but I may occasionally contribute a technical synonym; that's what we're all here for, as far as I can figure out.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Google books gives 5.7K hits for *"if you will be unable to attend"* against 74K for *"if you are unable..."*, but I must admit the former sounds "better" to me. Obviously [whoever] wants to be informed as early as possible, so they'd want you to do this when your inability to attend is still "in the future" rather than waiting until it actually comes to pass. I know it all nets down to the same thing in the real world, but somehow the "will" version makes me think I'm dealing with people who run a tighter ship.

Comment: @JohnLawler What do you pretend the tense of ‘will see’ is?You cannot just pick it apart in isolation and call ‘will’ a modal and ‘see’ the bare/citation form and stop there,satisfied that that’s all there is to it—any moreso than you can dissect a frog and call the resulting goo a frog.The entire phrase ‘will go’ is in the future, and if you will not condescend to call it the future tense, that is your peculiar problem.Thousands of text books have no problem with doing so. It is a useful way of speaking of things without splattering everybody with frog guts.Just translate ‘tense’ to **BLAH**.

Comment: Thousands of textbooks are spattered with frog guts, then. Too bad. I don't quite understand why terminology makes you so mad. But then there's lots of things I don't understand. Also too bad. If you really have questions, and don't just want to ask rhetorical questions, you are free to do so.

Comment: Technically it is correct to say that English has no future tense. Of course, using 'will' plus the infinitive is one way to refer to future time. But there are many other ways to refer to events in the future. It may therefore be unhelpful to the English language learner to refer to 'will + infinitive' as **the** future tense since this could imply that there is only one such tense or that 'will + infinitive' is the default way of referring to the future.

Comment: Exactly. Many (most?) of our readers here are English learners, not native speakers, and they actually need the facts about the language. Which they get, in any decent ESL classroom.

Comment: @Tchrist & John: Isn't it just a matter of definition in the end? John appears to adhere to the principle that a tense cannot be synthetic. That is a valid choice; but what is the main argument behind it exactly?

Comment: @Cerberus: To make the concept of _tense_ precise and therefore useful, instead of using _"tense"_ for anything in a sentence that vaguely reminds one of time, or of something one's third-grade teacher said about it. For instance, if _will_ is future tense, what tense is _may_ or _should_? Or _gonna_ or _oughta_? Or _tomorrow_ or _soon_ or _used to have to_? [The problem](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist) is not new.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yeah I understand the disadvantage of allowing analytic tenses. Then I am interested in your opinion about other labels that usually refer to single words, but sometimes also to several words, like *adjective* (red, far(-)fetched), or *noun* (blackbird, high school). Would you always want to refer to high school as two words? Is the word barrier really the basis for that? Can a reliable distinction between morphology and syntax be made? I suppose *will do* has more freedom in word order than *high school*, though (can be split up).

Comment: @JohnLawler: One more thing: a main argument for a analytic future tense is semantic symmetry. Our cultural perception of time divides it in past, present, and future. Of course the past tense is not always and not only about the past, but it is named after what we perceive as its most typical function, or the most typical part of its function. Just as a conjunction typically conjoins clauses, although it does not always do so.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Oh, and sorry to bury you in comments, but Latin also has many analytic tenses: all the passive perfect tenses are analytic, like *vocatus est*. Of course that is only a matter of convention, but the Romans no doubt did it for symmetry. And Greek has various "tenses" with a form of *to be* + participle too.

Comment: Sorry I missed these comments, @Cerberus. If I could, I'd add another answer here to deal with them (I think they deserve a good answer), but this is officially Closed and I can't do so. Too bad.