# "If I go.." vs. "If I will go.." referring to the future

Tags: american-english, future, conditionals, when

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Future tense in conditional clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/future-tense-in-conditional-clauses)

Which one is correct?

> option 1: *If I go there, I can meet her*

or

> option 2: *If I **will** go there, I can meet her*

I clearly remember, was told by English (not American) teacher that "If", "When" cannot be used with "will" in the above context. Though, I have seen few people in US saying like **option 2**

I do know that "If I **would** go there, I **could** meet her" is correct (or at least, think so).

Comment: See [Future tense in conditional clauses](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/future-tense-in-conditional-clauses) and [Is “even if…” followed by present or future tense?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54819/is-even-if-followed-by-present-or-future-tense)

Comment: Please consider accepting John Lawler's answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This topic seems to come up with some frequency here.
Your teacher was overgeneralizing, I'm afraid.

It's not **wrong** to use *will* this way; it's just that it may not mean what you want it to mean. In the case you mention, it means that you are commenting on the possibility that you may be willing to go there, which sounds at least odd, and seems very unlikely to be what you intend to mean.

Briefly, *will* is **not** *"the future tense"*; *will* is a [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html). That means it's got complicated meanings.

All modal auxiliaries like *will* or *must* have **two** kinds of meaning -- one logical (called "epistemic") meaning having to do with truth and probability, like

- *He must be the person they mentioned.*

and one social (called "deontic") meaning having to do with obligation and permission, like

- *He must be home by midnight.*

The reason why *will* is often called 'the future tense' in English classes is because it normally only uses its **epistemic** sense of *"sposta"*, and that's close enough. But *will* also has a **deontic** sense of *"wanna"* that shows up in phrases like *be willing to, will power, with a will, with the best will in the world, leave a will,* etc.

What happens when you use *will* in a hypothetical clause is that such clauses only allow the **deontic** sense of *will*, so you wind up talking not about what's sposta happen, but about who wants to do what.

So it's perfectly OK to say

- *If you will hand in your homework, I will grade it.*
- *Whether he will attend the concert is unknown.*
- *I'm not certain when he will sign it.*

if you mean

- *If you are willing to hand in your homework, I am willing to grade it.*
- *Whether he is willing to attend the concert is unknown.*
- *I'm not certain when he's going to get around to signing it.*

But only for the deontic *wanna* sense, not for the usual epistemic *sposta* sense, of *will*.

> **Edit:** I forgot to point out that this is a peculiarity of the interaction of two modals - the hypothetical clause construction and the modal auxiliary *will*. This is like having two strong magnetic fields together; their interactions can become, um, peculiar.
>
> In this case some logicians might say that the deontic interpretation of *will* in hypotheticals is forced pragmatically because the *sposta happen* epistemic sense is already covered by the hypothetical construction, so using it again **must** mean the deontic sense. Maybe so; I'm not sure, personally.

Comment: For the example "If you will hand in your homework, I will grade it" you ascribe a deontic sense to each *will*.  Isn't the second *will* epistemic?

Comment: John, your explanation is helpful (+1), but, I bet, even for native speakers is too scientific

Comment: +1 particularly for *"If you will hand in your homework, I will grade it."* That one seems natural to me as a native speaker, but I'm always noticing *slightly different* variations used by non-native speakers that don't work for me. Particularly, Europeans influenced by the fact that verb inflections in their languages work differently in respect of subjunctive, conditional clauses, etc.

Comment: Especially for native speakers.

Comment: @jwpat, the second _will_ could be either. I had to pick one for the example and I picked the distinctive one to emphasize the sense I was talking about.

Comment: Just to confuse things further, there is also a dynamic sense: *If you **will** keep asking stupid questions you'd better expect some stupid answers*.

Comment: Yes, it's a stressed form of the deontic _will_ and doesn't just mean 'be willing to', but rather 'insist on (continuing to)'.

Comment: Sorry, folks, but "If you will keep asking stupid questions, you'd etc." even by hoi polloi speech habits (which are fine, I don't hold their feet to the fire, only  yours), is not exactly standard phrasing. And the homework thing works only in contexts where both clauses take will (that's the trick there) and requires a prior "situation". One does not say it ex nihllo.

Comment: What about the *will* in this sentence: *"If aspirin will ease my headache, I will take a couple tonight instead of this horrible medicine"*? Why is it acceptable, if the *will* doesn't have a deontic sense (as I believe it doesn't)?

Comment: And what about: *"If it will rain later, I'll bring my umbrella"*? // Also, do these restrictions on the occurrence of *will* in *if* clauses also apply to the other future tense construction, *be going to*?

Comment: @MrReality: Both of those work under the condition of the speaker accepting the epistemic _will_ as predictable and reliable. You can introduce either clause with _if it is a fact that_ without changing meaning. As for _gonna_, it's OK in hypotheticals: _If it's gonna rain, I'm goin home,_ but *_If it will rain, I'm going home/I'll go home._

Comment: So is this the only exception to the usual rule that "use of modal *will* in hypotheticals allows a deontic reading only"? // And do you have any references where I can read up more on this/these exception(s) -- I've read an answer or two related to this exception on this site but I really liked how you explained it just now, so would love to know more?

Comment: _Will,_ like all modals, is often ambiguous between epistemic and deontic; it's restricted in its senses in hypotheticals, but that's because they're hypothetical. Statements about probability, certainty, and likelihood in frankly imaginary contexts are not fit subjects for universal rules.

Comment: @JohnLawler, re: your comment dated Jan 5, I'm confused whether you meant to write "**predictive** and reliable" instead of "predictable and reliable"? If you did in fact mean *predictable*, then would I be correct in deducing that: as a proposition in the *if* clause gets less and less predictable, the acceptability of the *will* there in the *if* clause reduces accordingly too?

Answer (score 5):

"If I will go there" (or any other "if/when ... will ") is not normal in any variety of English AFAIK.

"If I would go there" appears to be common in colloquial American English, but is not in my (British) idiolect.

Comment: [doorbell: ring, ring] "Ah, that will be John now." Yes, right? Now, as regards conditionals, I'm with you.And though some (emphasis on some) AmE speakers say "If I would go there", I surely do not. In fact, if you listen to some speakers (even a British journalist interviewing Kushner said just today: Do you wish you didn't do x for hadn't done x), who consistently replace would with simple past, you realize they are screwing up the idea of past possibility.

Comment: "That will be John now" is the modal _will_ in its epistemic meaning, as opposed to its more usual deontic one. A lot of people seem to have difficulty with _irrealis_ conditionals - it is an area where English is in flux.

Comment: Yes, absolutely but "Do you wish you didn't do it?" messes with my humours, especially from those who are the media "elite", as it were.

Comment: @ColinFine, re: your reply to Lambie, what did you mean by "as opposed to its more usual *deontic* one"? As per my knowledge, the usual sense of *will*,  as in "I will go to the hospital today.", is the *epistemic* (logical necessity/probability) one, not the deontic (social obligation/permission) one.

Comment: @MrReality: The _will_ in _That will be John now_ has the force of "I conclude that": a typical epistemic meaning for a modal: it is about the state of the speaker's knowledge. You have chosen a first person _will_, so it easy to confuse that with an epistemic use, but _He will go_ is not epistemic. I think also that "social obligation/permission" is too narrow for "deontic": that would exclude the non-epistemic sense of "can" for example.

Comment: Maybe the defintions of the terms differ -- I don't consider the "ability" sense of *can* to be expressing *deontic modality*, rather I've heard the term *alethic* modality used for it and subscribe to it myself. Can you provide a link for the definitions of the terms you subscribe to? JLawler's answer above is in agreement with me, "The reason why *will* is often called 'the future tense' in English classes is because it normally only uses its epistemic sense of "*sposta*", and that's close enough. But *will* also has a deontic sense of "*wanna*" ...

Comment: ... that shows up in phrases like *be willing to, will power, with a will, with the best will in the world, leave a will,* etc."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's something called an *ellipted conditional clause* as in:

```
If you think the weather will be fine, we'll go for a walk.

If (you think) the weather will be fine, we'll go for a walk.

If the weather will be fine, we'll go for a walk.
```

I doubt that can be applied to your example, as it is quite self-explanatory in this regard, but there's some general possibility. However, I don't know exactly whether this construction is widely accepted or considered non-standard.

Comment: Cite a reference?

Comment: That's something I got from my grammar teacher.