# "It will depend on what I [will] see"

Tags: modal-verbs, future, subjunctive-mood

I want to refer to the future. When someone asks me: "what are you going to do when you have a chance to look at [something]?". How should I reply?

Basically, the question is which one is correct (or none):

> It will depend on what I see

or

> It will depend on what I **will** see

Comment: Definately the former. The complete thought here is:  *It will depend on what I see* [when I look at it].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly don't want "future tense" for "see". Many [if not most](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20depends%20on%20what%20I,it%20will%20depend%20on%20what%20I&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) native speakers wouldn't use it for "depend" either...

> It depends on what I see.

Comment: The "it will depend on" part creates a hypothetical environment, like an _if_-clause, and the same [rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61299/if-i-go-vs-if-i-will-go-referring-to-the-future/61308#61308) about deontic vs epistemic usages of modal _will_ apply.

Comment: @John Lawler: You are not wrong. But I think one could equally say that *the same rules...**would** apply* (should anyone wish to check), or that those same rules ***do** apply* (now and for the immediately-foreseeable future).

Comment: The italics just aren't as noticeable as they ought to be in comments, alas. What I said was "the same rules about deontic vs epistemic usages of modal ***will*** ... apply". Of course, the intonation and pause before _apply_ didn't show up, and you couldn't tell that _will_ was being mentioned instead of used. I agree, _do apply_ would be unambiguous, but my whole point was that this is an unexceptionable instance of a well-documented phenomenon and I wished to avoid sounding like a stressed **do** sounds. As you can see, I write like I talk, and vice versa.

Comment: @John: I know I'm not as well-versed in the terminology as you, but I think I understand *deontic* as having some element of "attitude" (volition/obligation/etc.), where *epistemic* is just about facts/probabilities. So I took you italicisation to be a "parenthetical joke" deliberately toying with the distinction *(the rules **will** apply, because I hereby decree it to be so! :).*

Comment: No, it was just a citation. Would that I were that clever. My unconscious may be, but I rarely notice it until too late.

Comment: I wish you weren't so categorical in your answer. After all, the use of *will* here has its reasons and its rationale. Both the sentences are correct.

Comment: @Kris: You mean you genuinely think that *"It will depend on what I **will** see"* constitutes a "normal" construction? If that's the case I think you should post it as an answer and see if anyone else agrees (I think almost no-one would). As regards my second point, I only said *many if not most* speakers wouldn't use future tense "will depend", which the NGram link shows to be the case by a factor of about 20:1, so I don't think I'm making an unjustified claim there.