# Using 'would' to form reasons

Tags: tenses, questions, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

In the following examples:

- Why would anyone want to eat something so horrible?
- Who would live for forever?
- Why would I ever lie to you?

Is 'would' being used to refer to time in future or past Or Is it just being used to form facts and reasons or arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these,'would' is signalling that the statements are hypothetical or counterfactual.

"Why would anyone want to eat something so horrible?" indicates that you don't expect anyone is going to eat the horrible something.

"Who would live for forever?'indicates that nobody is going live forever.

"Why would I ever lie to you?" indicates that you do not lie to the listener,

Comment: Isn't that due to the 'why', not the 'would'?

Comment: 'Why' marks it as a question. 'Would' marks it as hypothetical or counterfactual. "Why did you kick me?" is a question, but it is not hypothetical, because you really have been kicked. "Why would you kick me?" is hypothetical - you have not been kicked.

Comment: "What would you say?" isn't hypo' either?

Comment: Hmmm! +1 anyway

Comment: "I would hate to eat something horrible." is not a question. Is it still a hypothetical (something you can imagine happening in future) statement? How else who you use 'would' to form reasons?

Comment: @Kris- Why do you say "What would you say" isn't hypothetical? It is asking '[ If *<something>* ], what would you say?"

Comment: @Jim Conditional?

Comment: @Kris- Ah, I see. So there is a fine line between conditional and hypothetical I think.  How would you describe that difference?

Comment: @kris~ 'what would you say?' is hypothetical. 'What did you say? is real. It is not really conditional because there is no condition stated, though you might argue that one is usually implied by 'you'.

Comment: I applied the same logic: "since there no explicit 'if', it's not hypo' -- is it then even conditional?"

Comment: Hypothetical doesn't need an 'if', it just needs to be basically a thought - hypothetical or counterfactual. A conditional needs two parts. A condition clause that sets the condition, and a result clause that happens if the condition is met.

Comment: "Hypothetical doesn't need an 'if', it just needs to be basically a thought - hypothetical or counterfactual." - Hmmm!

Answer (score 1):

The [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html) *would* was originally the past tense form of the modal *will*. As such, it has some of the same senses as *will*, specifically, in this case, that sense of "[be willing to](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299)" that shows up when *will* is used in hypothetical clauses:

- *if he will put down the gun,*

which means *if he **is willing** to put down the gun*.

So the rather idiomatic question construction

> `Wh-` *would* `X Infinitive`?

means

- *Why/Who/When/Where/.. would* `X` ***be willing to*** `Infinitive`?

with the clear implication that the speaker is surprised at the possibility.

Conveying that emotion of surprise is the construction's most important function.
Hence it usually appears as a rhetorical question.