# Is the "will" in "can and will" necessary?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, legalese, redundancy

Anyone who's ever seen much American film or television has heard some variation of the following sentences countless times:

> You have the right to remain silent.  If you choose to give up that right, anything you say **can and will** be used against you in a court of law.

And the phrase "can and will" can be seen in other contexts as well.  My issue with this is not the "can" part, but the "will" part.  "Can" implies that anything you say *may* be used against you in court, but "will" asserts that it is a certainty.  The person being arrested could obviously say any number of things that would not be of any use in a case against them, so it's not true to say that anything they say *will* be used, only that it *can* be.

Does Hollywood have it wrong?  I looked around to see what the official text of the Miranda warning is, and it seems there isn't any - it varies from one jurisdiction to the next, but the Hollywood version is always pretty much the same.  (The Miranda *rights* are universal, but the actual words to be spoken by the arresting officer are not mandated so long as the rights are properly delineated.)

And more to the point, is this phrase just being incorrectly used in these (and other) cases?  Does "can and will" maybe bear more legal weight than simply "can"?  Or could the officer leave out the "and will" part and consider the Miranda warning just as properly given without it?

Comment: This isn't a bad point, but I think it entirely depends on what the PERP says, if they even say anything that at all. Saying nothing at all renders "will" void, unless silence suddenly becomes incriminating.

Comment: I am not sure about the grammar part, but Hollywood doesn't have it wrong -- see the case document [Miranda v. Arizona - 384 U.S. 436 (1966)](http://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/384/436/case.html): "... The warning of the right to remain silent must be accompanied by the explanation that anything said ***can and will*** be used against the individual in court. ..."

Comment: Per grammar, this is a NARQ. Both *can* & *will* are well defined and they are used in their standard sense here. If you are debating the interpretation and its implications, that would be off-topic. Either way the Q needs to be closed.

Comment: Perhaps it's presenting a worst-case scenario to cover themselves. If they use what the accused says, they can say, "We told you we'd use it!" If they don't, the accused isn't going to complain that they broke their promise.

Comment: Suppose, after being given the warning, I said "I am a black man." The police have just guaranteed that will be used against me in a court of law, haven't they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *will* in *can and will* is not the **[epistemic](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html)** ("predicted/expected future") *will*, but rather the **deontic** ("be willing to") *will*, the one that shows up in hypothetical clauses (where you were probably told in school that you "[can't use the future tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299)").

- *If he **will** hand in his homework, I **will** correct it.*

The first *will* is deontic only; the second could be either deontic or epistemic.
(Ambiguity, too!  Aren't modals fun?)

That means that, since the *can* part means *be able* and the *will* part means *be willing*, the whole phrase *can and will* is just a verbing of *able and willing*. And both parts are necessary.

[Modals](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Modality.pdf) are tricky that way; every modal auxiliary has an epistemic and a deontic sense, and you always have to figure out which one is intended, because they're not marked and each reading of each modal has its own unique grammar.

Comment: +1 for an actual grammatical justification.  This is probably the closest to a real answer this can have.  I'm still not sure both parts are really needed - it doesn't matter what the prosecution is _willing_ to do so long as it allowed (which is already covered by "can").  Just seems a bit off logically.

Comment: I reject the deontic "be willing to" because it doesn't comply with the subject. While the perp may have to understand that he/she is willing to comply, the subject of the sentence is "anything," which doesn't have a will. The matter is one of logic, not one of grammar. The authority issuing the rights does not have the right/ability to say what "will" (a certainty) be used in court. The lawyers and judge will decide what can be used in court at the time of trial. The arresting cop has no authority to declare that in advance.

Comment: J. Lawler: I am sure your explanation is correct. It's just that as a layman, the specifics are over my head. I don't understand the differences b/w the two types of "wills" and I still don't understand why "can" is needed.

Comment: Even if your'e able to cut off your head, you are probly not willing to do it. On the other hand, you might be willing but not able, like a prisoner. Being willing and being able are independent. As for modals, follow the links [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html), [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), in that order. They won't tell you everything, but they will tell you something. If you're interested in learning logic and English grammar. And if you can learn English, you can learn English grammar.

Comment: How about this pair? 1. _When you're willing to hand in his homework, I will correct it._ 2. _When you will hand in his homework, I will correct it._ I mean, does 2 ever work? If not, why not?

Comment: Because _when you will hand in his homework_ is a noun clause, not a temporal adverb clause. It could easily be the subject of _is a mystery_, for instance.

Comment: @JohnLawler What I'm asking is why you can't use _will_ in a temporal adverb clause, whereas you can in a conditional _if_ clause.

Comment: @JK2 Why are you sure there is a reason, and what would you consider a reasonable answer?

Comment: @JohnLawler Because theoretically I can't figure out why we can't use the deontic _will_ in a temporal adverb clause, can you?

Comment: No, but theories aren't sposta explain individual details. That's a fact about _will_, and there are facts about every other modal that we can't explain, like why is _shall_ in the US limited to first person questions? _Shall I ..?_ and _Shall we ...?_ are **IT**. _Shall_ is not otherwise used in the US. Why would one expect a theory to explain this?

Comment: @JohnLawler Hate to tell you this, but if you don't specify who you're talking to, I don't get the notification.// On to your comment: But you were able to figure out why we can use the deontic _will_ in a conditional adjunct. Regarding your _shall_ question, my ability to explain that question has nothing to do with your general proposition that you can't explain individual details, at least one of which you yourself did in your own answer. That's of course not to say that I can't explain your _shall_ question. I certainly can. But I'm not going to here, because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly the *can* is unnecessary, as it's entailed in the *will*; anything one will do one by definition can do, while not everything one can do one will do.

However, considering the context, there is a value in making the two statements severally:

> We have the legal right to...
>
> We have a policy of doing...

While one would obviously hope that people would not have a policy of doing things they had no right to do, in a context of stating different people's rights in a given situation, it's worth emphasising.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of grammar, ***can*** is unnecessary (except for extra emphasis) as it is implicit in ***will*** (as @JonHanna says).

On the other hand, it has always struck me (as a Brit.) that the ***will*** is strictly incorrect. I imagine that the person being questioned may well say many things that subsequently are **not** in fact used against him: either because they are irrelevant or neutral, or because the prosecution choose not to use them for whatever reason.

I've always thought it ought to be:

> *... anything you say can and **may** be used against you in a court of law.*

But legalese is notorious for stating the obvious, repeating itself in different words, using ten words when one will do, and trying to avoid all possible loopholes. They particularly want to avoid a lawyer arguing that something their client said cannot be used in court because the suspect wasn't properly warned.

Comment: Actually, there isn't a set language throughout all agencies affected by Miranda v Arizona, never mind those in other jurisdictions that have a similar concept (such as the UK). There is though there is a set list of facts that must be stated. "Can and will" is indeed found in the set language used by some particular departments and agencies in fulfilling that obligation.

Comment: That said. I do agree that *may* would be a better choice.

Comment: I've no doubt that there are similar clauses in most English-speaking democracies, and indeed other countries as well.  It's more a question of the general use of the phrase rather than its specific use in the Miranda warning.  Of course "may" is also unnecessary - if something can be done, it should go without saying that it may (or may not) be done - these are the only two options, after all.

Answer (score 0):

The "can" and "will" are both useful from the point of view of legal phraseology.

"Can" is a warning that by speaking you are abandoning caution, which you are legally entitled to exercise. "Where a word is worth a silver dollar, silence can be worth a $20 gold piece."

"Will" is a warning that your speech is irrevocable and could cause you harm.

Using either word alone would not give sufficient warning. Using both together implies "you are advised not to speak unless it is clearly in your best interest". And then, should you be so foolish as to speak, it's *your* problem.

1. "Can" alone could be considered insufficient warning: "Yeah, sure, it CAN be used, but WILL it?"
2. "Will" alone implies a threat. ("So you'll take EVERYTHING I say and use it against me? Thus I refuse to say anything in my defense, even if it could help me at the present moment.") This could give grounds at trial that there was unduly aggressive behavior in the arrest procedure in threatening the suspect with certain punishment for anything he would say, even in his own defense.