# "Will" not used for somebody else's intentions/plans

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, future, will-be-going, will-future

Page 576 of Collins English Usage reads

> When you are talking about your own intentions, you use *will* or *be
> going to*. When you are talking about someone else's intentions, you
> use *be going to*.
>
> *I'll ring you tonight.*
>
> *They're going to have a party.*

Why can't **will** be used for somebody else's?

Comment: "They will / They'll have a party" is perfectly grammatical, though standalone, your variant is far more idiomatic.

Comment: It can. There's nothing wrong with "They _will_ have a party" or, in the short form "_They'll_ have a party". Also "The doctor will see you  now, sir".

Comment: This is one in the series of recent questions by GJC seeking explanations of various pronouncements in Collins English Usage that seem arbitrary (at least so far as one can judge from the quotations). These questions are on topic and well justified, because the pronouncements really are puzzling, but it is still difficult to see how one would go about answering them. Many of us may have a reaction 'I don't see any reason for these pronouncements', but can't say anything more than that: one can't engage the authors' reasons for these pronouncements if one doesn't know what they are.

Comment: At this point, CEU should be put back on the shelf and become unconsulted.

Comment: The Collins advice is essentially correct in most contexts in which the statement is likely. For example, if you are talking with your partner about your neighbours, then "_(Did you know) They're going to have a party next weekend_" seems more natural than "_(Did you know) They're will have a party next weekend_". I have the Collins book and I think it gives good advice to English language learners. It does not try to cover all possibilities such as a descriptive grammar like the CGEL aspires to do.

Comment: @John Lawler. Which pedagogic grammar would you recommend for English language learners?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that the OP was quoting Collins English Usage. I wonder what the same book says about the common abbreviations "he'll", "she'll", and "they'll".

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an example of poorly supported prescriptivist grammar.

From *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* p192-194, a modern descriptivist grammar,

> Dynamic Modality
>
> Under this heading we consider those uses of *will* where dispositions
> or properties of the subject-referent are involved.
>
> (a) Volition
>
> [38] i Jill **won’t** sign the form.
>
> ii They have found someone [who **will** stand in for you while you’re
> away].
>
> iii I **will** be back before six.
>
> Example [i] implies unwillingness or refusal on Jill’s part; in[ii]
> ***will*** might be glossed as “is prepared/willing to”; and in [iii] the auxiliary conveys the idea of intention.
>
> ...
>
> [39] i I ***WILL*** solve this problem. [strongly stressed modal]
>
> ii ***Will*** you lend me your pen? [closed interrogative]
>
> iii I’ll wash if [you ***will*** dry]. [conditional protasis]
>
> A strongly stressed ***will***, especially with a 1st person subject, tends
> to convey determination. A closed interrogative, especially with a
> 2nd person subject, characteristically questions willingness and
> indirectly conveys a request (Ch. 10, §9.6.1). Futurity ***will*** rarely
> occurs in a conditional protasis, as noted above, but volitional ***will***
> is quite unexceptionable, as in [iii], where your willingness is
> clearly part of the proposition that is conditionally entertained.
>
> Extension to inanimates
>
> Volition implies a human or animate agent, but
> something akin to a metaphorical extension of volitional ***will*** is found
> with inanimates when it is a matter of satisfying
> human wants,as in *The lawnmower won’t start* (someone is trying to start it)or >*The books won’t fit on one shelf*. These again appear freely in
> conditionals: *Give me a call if the engine won’t start*.

The examples given in [38-39] (excepting the first person ones) can all be interpreted as expressing the intentions of other people.

Comment: The CGEL discussion makes too many distinctions, I think. All of these are simply [deontic _will_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115478/15299) in various contexts. The semantics has the same root as _willing, with a will,_ and _make a will_; it's about somebody's preference, and specifying all possible preferences is beyond Herculean.