# Why is this sentence ungrammatical?

Tags: tenses

"If they would have been painted this afternoon, the walls would be completely dry by tomorrow evening."

The quoted sentence is ungrammatical. I believe it has something to do with tense, but I do not believe that the 'if...would be' structure requires parallelism. So what is wrong with this sentence? Thank you.

Comment: See also: [ell.se]

Comment: Can you explain why you "do not believe that the 'if...would be' structure requires parallelism"?

Answer (score 3):

We don't normally like to use *would* in conditional antecedents (read *if*-clauses). The standard phrasing for your sentence would be:

- If they **had** been painted this afternoon, the walls would be completely dry by tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit "will" is suppressed in "if" clauses.  For instance, "I buy a car tomorrow" doesn't sound right unless there is some sort of schedule involved, and since it's a future action, you'd say "I will buy a car tomorrow."  Yet in an "if" clause, the "will" disappears: "If I buy a car tomorrow, then ..."

Now (getting to the point), in your case, the sentence "They would have been painted ..." is grammatically the past tense of "They will have been painted ..."  But the sentence is in an "if" clause, so the "will" is suppressed, as is normal, and we get the past tense form of "They have been painted ...", which is "They had been painted ...".

I know, the "would" isn't really a logical past tense, but grammatically, it sometimes behaves as though it were.

So the answer to your question is this: The grammatical problem is that "will" wasn't deleted from the "if" clause.

Comment: Epistemic _will_ -- the "future tense" -- is banned in hypothetical clauses. Consequently if _will_ appears in an _if_-clause, it get [a deontic 'be willing to/want to' reading](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299).  English teachers are prone to tell their students that you can't use the future tense in an if clause, for gods know what reason. This tends to confuse everybody.