# If that won't happen, we'll have no choice

Tags: conditionals

*The decision has been made and we ask for just one thing, an immediate positive intervention of Zaccagnini. **If that won't happen**, we'll have no choice but to execute the sentence, you understand?*

This is the part of a monologue from the movie The Moro Affair. I would like to ask whether the clause "If that won't happen" is OK. I am aware that in some cases there is needed to use the future in the if-clause, like "If it will help you, I will go to a dentist with you". But my sentence contains after all type 2 of the conditional where the pattern is: if-clause – Simple present and main clause – Simple future. So I would await "If that doesn't happen, we'll have no choice".

Comment: *If (we accept that the current situation is that) that **won't** happen, **we have** no choice but to [blah blah]*.

Comment: @WS2: You could say *If that won't happen* = ***Since** it won't happen* in some contexts, whereas *If it doesn't happen* = ***In the event that** it doesn't...*

Comment: I thought that in my sentence fits your second version, i.e. If it doesn't happen = In the event that it doesn't.

Comment: This is the [deontic sense of _will_, meaning _be willing_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299). It's the only interpretation of _will_ allowed in _if_-clauses. We have asked for one thing to happen; if this won't happen -- i.e, if `they` won't allow it to happen -- then, ...

Comment: @John Lawler I can accept what you say about the deontic sense of *will*, and that it is the only one allowed in an *if clause*. On that basis I am going to delete my earlier comment. But what I don't understand is how an inanimate pronoun *it*, can *be willing*.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think not. This looks to me like a different situation which licenses *will* in the protasis, what Declerck and Reed call a "closed condition". Here, what the protasis expresses is not a contingency but an accepted fact, and *if* does not mean "in the event that" but  *given the fact that*.

Comment: @StoneyB - So the speaker expects "an immediate positive intervention of Zaccagnini" will not happen. But it does not make much sense…

Comment: @bart-leby It amounts to "All we ask is that Zaccagnini intervene. You tell me that he will not, so we will have no choice but to execute the sentence"

Comment: @StoneyB It is an unlikely structure in my view. Would I say *I'm seeking the intervention of the Mayor. If that won't happen permission will not be granted*? I think not. I would say something like: *I'm seeking the intervention... If that does not happen then...* It does not seem idiomatic to say *If that won't happen...*

Comment: @WS2 I agree that it's unlikely in this context. I'm merely pointing out a context in which it would be acceptable--think of it as bearing a strong emphasis on *won't*: "If (as you say) that **won't** happen, we'll have no choice".

Comment: @StoneyB I still think I'd say possibly *Unless there is an intent for it to happen...* I would never expect to see *won't* in this context and if I did I would puzzle over it.

Answer (score 1):

'If that doesn't happen' is the right form.

'Won't' comes from 'will not', so applies a person deciding not to do something. 'Doesn't' comes from 'do', so just describes a circumstance.

You might use 'if you won't' or 'if it doesn't' but not 'if it won't.'

Edit

Just realised it is more complex.

'Will it happen' and 'it won't happen' and 'it will happen' are all  fine, but they never get combined with 'if'.

So

> will it happen?
>   if it doesn't, we'll be fine.