# Condition in future

Tags: conditionals, future

Is it correct to say "Can the period be changed if I will not get the visa in time?"

Comment: "Correct" in what sense?

Comment: No, it's not correct. In an _if_-clause, the modal auxiliary _will_ [can only have its deontic sense of 'be willing to'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299); it can't be used in its epistemic sense of 'be expected to'.

Answer (score 2):

English does not use the future tense in a conditional, even if the condition occurs in the future. The present is used instead. So:

> **CORRECT**: If I get the visa I will go to the UK
>
> **INCORRECT**: If I will get the visa I will go to the UK.

and

> **CORRECT**:I will go to the UK if I get the visa.

The negative forces us to include a "do", so the correct version of your sentence is:

> Can the period be changed if I **do** not get the visa in time?