# Can the construction " to be going to do something" be used in if-clauses in Conditionals?

Tags: grammar

I'm doing some research on conditionals and this questions bothers me.
There are cases when will is ok in if-clauses, but is it ok to use "to be going to" in if-clauses?

Ngram gives some examples such as

- It'll be there by seven in the morning if I'm going to leave it.
- If I'm going to be less like Katherine, I'll have to work on reining in my honest opinions some.

But in general, I haven't managed to find any info about this.

I believe it's not really typical to use this construction in if-clauses, but if so, what about the examples above?

Comment: _Will_ is OK in _if_-clauses [when it's the deontic "be willing to" sense of _will_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299). There are no such lexical restrictions on its periphrastic modal analog _be going to_. It can be used in just about any _if_ clause to represent the future. E.g, _If it (*will/is going to) rain, I'm staying home._

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you very much!) btw is there any info why the epistemic sense that "will" has is inappropriate in if-clauses? (Especially, if there are no restrictions of this kind connected with be going to)

Comment: @Marshmellow: you're welcome. It's just one more oddity of modal auxiliaries. Each one is unique and has unique affordances and prohibitions; they're effectively idioms.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Will* is OK in *if*-clauses [when it's the deontic "be willing to" sense of *will*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299). There are no such lexical restrictions on its periphrastic modal analog *be going to*. It can be used in just about any *if* clause to represent the future. E.g, *If it (*will/is going to) rain, I'm staying home.*